# Chrome 83 select box took long time to display

Tags: google-chrome, html-select

Chrome 83 updated new style to form controls https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/05/nic83#forms

But because of this, my chrome suddenly takes about 1 sec to load select box in any size (even with 1 child, see the image example below)

Anyone has the same issue? Is there anything i can do to fix this?

[Chrome 83 select box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPE3x.gif)